# how to use configuration file to log in java

Tags: logging

i have more than one program to write to log files. each program need to write to separate log files.i am doing this to differentiate the log entries based on the process of the program. Instead of using FileHandler class, i want to configure a file and use it for logging. Can someone please help me with an example ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
$ java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/path/to/app.properties MainClass
```

This is command line through which you can set your logging configuration file.

Comment: thanks for ur response. What i want to know is how to log into differrent files. Here is the scenario. i have five java programs and in each program i have to create logging functionality. But each java program has to have its own log file , i mean separate log files. ex: l1.txt,l2.txt,l3.txt,l4.txt and l5.txt are the five log files. From the log4j tutorials i see that i can create a logger for a single file. but i dont find how to create for many files and how to allow programs to access it particular appender to log into the corressponding file. i am looking for such a program to implement.